# Testing setInterval() with sinon.fakeTimers not working?

Tags: reactjs, setinterval, sinon

I have a action in my componentDidMount that fetches images from Reddit after 30000ms. I want to test this but cannot figure it out?!?! Any suggestions?

```
    componentDidMount() {
       this.getHumorEvery(30000)
    }

    getHumorEvery = async (ms) => {
        await this.props.getHumor()

        return setInterval(() => {
            this.props.getHumor()
    }, ms)
```

So getHumor() gets call immediately. Then after 30000ms it gets called again and so on.

Then my test...

```
it('should refetch images every 30000 ms', () => {
    const clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
    const getHumorSpy = sinon.spy();

    renderComponent(requiredProps({ getHumor: getHumorSpy }));
    clock.tick(30000)

    sinon.assert.calledTwice(getHumorSpy)
```

})

Test fails because getHumor is only called once. The setInterval() never gets fired?

Comment: Is your setInterval callback ever called? If so, is `this.props.getHumor` defined inside the callback, and are you sure it's the sinon spy?

Comment: Yes if you console.log(setInterval) right before the setInterval is called, and then put another console.log() inside the setTimeout and then run the tests the outcome is....

1) setInterval logs out the stubbed setInterval
2) the console.log() inside setInterval never gets logged out

Therefore, it seems that yes, setInterval is stubbed correctly, but yet it never calls setInerval()

Comment: Did you try increasing the tick to something higher, like `40000`?

Comment: I did..I tried a couple different times.

Comment: Why is the `async/await` needed in the `getHumorEvery()`? I think that is the cause.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calling then on promises and calling await in an async function queues code for the event loop that doesn't execute until the current synchronous code completes and the clock ticks.  Similarly, setTimeout usually adds code to the queue that must also wait until the next clock tick.

[Sinon fake timers](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v6.1.4/fake-timers/) "are synchronous implementations of setTimeout and friends" that "overwrite the global functions" and manage the code queued with setTimeout and similar globals and call it synchronously when the simulated clock ticks.

This disconnect between code that is still queued for the event loop and code that was previously queued for the event loop but is now called synchronously can cause issues (like [this](https://github.com/sinonjs/lolex/pull/105) and [this](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/1739)).

These issues can often be resolved by inserting a manual cycle of the event loop to allow any pending code in the queue to execute before synchronously simulating a clock tick.

In this case turning the test into an async function and calling await on a resolved Promise gives the pending code in the queue a chance to run before the synchronous clock tick which allows the code to behave as expected and assert properly:

```
it('should refetch images every 30000 ms', async () => {
    const clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
    const getHumorSpy = sinon.spy();

    renderComponent(requiredProps({ getHumor: getHumorSpy }));

    // let event loop cycle
    await Promise.resolve();

    clock.tick(30000);
    sinon.assert.calledTwice(getHumorSpy);
})
```

Comment: I would try replacing `clock.tick` with `clock.tickAsync` and avoid the extra `await Promise.resolve();`